# partial derivation 2nd order for a function defined by parts

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

[image]

Do this contradict Clairaut? How to do c) and whats the others results just to confirm if i am right. Thanks

Comment: Mixed partial derivatives (such as $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$) are only guaranteed to be equal when they are continuous. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialDerivative.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, to compute $f_x(x,y)$ we treat $y$ as constant and take the derivative w.r.t. $x$, using the quotient rule. We have $$f_x(x,y) = \frac{(3x^2y - y^3)(x^2 + y^2) - (x^3y - xy^3)(2x)}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}$$
To calculate $f_y(x,y)$ its the same thing. You can use Wolfram Alpha, for instance, to check. From here on, you have to use the **definition** of the partial derivatives. Again, I'll do one of them. $$\begin{align} f_x(0,0) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0 + h, 0) - f(0,0)}{h} \\ &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac {h^3 0 - h0^3}{h^2 + 0^2} - 0}{h} \\ &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{0}{h} = 0 \end{align}$$
It is very important that you understand the definition. This way you can solve problems like this and analyze complicated points like $(0,0)$ in your function $f$. To calculate second order mixed derivatives on that point, we use the definition **again**. Here I prefer to use Leibniz's notation, to make clear which variable we are taking derivatives w.r.t.. I'll compute $f_{yx}(0,0) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}(0,0)$. Now: $$\begin{align} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right) (0,0) &= \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0+k) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)}{k} \\ &= \lim_{k \to 0} \frac {\frac {(3.0^2 k - k^3)(0^2 + k^2) -(0^3 k - 0 k^3)(2 \cdot 0)}{(0^2 + k^2)^2} - 0}{k} \\ &= \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{\frac{-k^5}{k^4}}{k} \\ &= \lim_{k \to 0} -1 = -1 \end{align}$$

You do the other one to practice. Always play close attention to what gets plugged where. In the first line of every calculation I did, I did it like this to help you see what is happening.

Important: I got $-1$ instead of $1$ like your text says, because of a matter of **convention**. Your text must mean $f_{yx}(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right) (x,y)$, opposing what I had interpreted. Again, I am not wrong, and neither is your text. I had not counted on this problem, but now it doesn't matter, more information to you. I hope you really don't get confused by this. And the mixed partials being different does **not** contradict Clairaut-Schwartz, because the derivatives aren't continuous. You can see for yourself, based on my calculations above that probably $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f_x(x,y) \neq f_x(0,0)$. If this limit actually works, then the analogous with $f_y(x,y)$, or $f_{xy}, f_{yx}$ certainly fails. I hope this makes things clearer to you. Good studies (: