# Partial derivative of a discontinuous function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$$f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{array}{l l}
\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} & \quad \text{if $(x,y)\neq(0,0),$}\\
0                   & \quad \text{if $(x,y)=(0,0).$}
\end{array} \right.$$

I know that this function is a standard example of a discontinuous function whose first order partial derivatives exist. I was just wondering if $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y}$ exist at the origin.

My work so far:
$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y}(0,0)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(h,0)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)}{h}$$

Sub in $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\dfrac{2x(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$, I get $$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y}(0,0)= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{2}{h^2}=0$$

I don't know whether what I've got is correct. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Note that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{2}{h^2}\ne 0$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Omg what a stupid mistake that I made! Thanks so much for pointing it out!

Comment: Here's a basic question to think about. If that partial derivative exists at the origin, then $\partial f/\partial y(x,0)$ must be continuous at $x=0$. Is it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [partial derivation 2nd order for a function defined by parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833435/partial-derivation-2nd-order-for-a-function-defined-by-parts)